# Complex Appear In Keynote Presentation

Tags: keynote, animation

In my presentation, I have a slide with six lines.  I'm trying to set it up so lines 1 and 6 will appear, then 2 and 5, and finally 3 and 4.  I know I could throw a box over them and have the boxes disappear but there must be a better way to do this.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 groups of the line pairs. Then schedule the appearance of the groups via the Inspector.